# Cross-region database latency much slower than ping?

Tags: networking, database

We were recently discovering that an API request had about 500ms response times as seen in the logs from our server. We realized this was because we had our API running in aws-west-1 but a remote DB running in aws-east-1. By moving them into the same region, aws-east-1, we saw a drop down from ~500ms to <50ms response times. We do one Mongo query (I believe this is the case based on Mongoose ORM) to fetch all documents in a collection of about 80kb worth of data and do minimal processing on the server.

However, when I look at ping times, I see [much lower](https://www.cloudping.co/grid) times of around 65ms ping between the two regions. So how is it the case that there's a ~65ms ping between the two regions but moving them into the same region improved latency by about 450ms? I was thinking maybe it had to do with the fact that there's a TCP handshake but that should only be about 1.5x the ping value from my understanding? Is there a lot more additional chatter that I'm not accounting for in my calculations?

I'm more curious than anything why this caused such a dramatic drop and why it was so much slower before even though the cross-region ping was much less than the increased latency we saw.

Answer (score 1):

There's not one definitive answer.  Here are a few possibilities:

1. You moved the database/app server from a heavily-used server to a
   lighter one.
2. Pings are handled by a low level process in the network stack.  The
   server OS will respond faster than an application will.
3. Pings are small packets (32 or 64 bytes).  Compare that to 80,000
   bytes.
4. When you moved the server, you may have restarted some process that
   was having problems.